# A story about a planet whose inhabitants stole things from astronauts

Tags: story-identification, space

There was a series of stories about space exploration. One of them goes like this:
A group of explorers landed on a planet and established a camp. After some time they realised their stuff was stolen. Explorers became somehow frustrated, and apparently creatures who messed with them returned what they'd taken. Space pioneers took that as a sign of intelligent life (apparently it was a first encounter).
Their mission was immediately aborted.

Any hints?

Comment: Was this "series of stories" in a book? Were the stories all by the same author? Was it the same characters visiting one different planet after another, sort of like *Star Trek*? Can you remember anything about any of the other stories? About how long ago did you read it?

Comment: Were there any nonhumans or robots or androids in the space crew, or was it all humans?

Comment: Why did they abort the mission at the first sign of intelligent life? Were they operating under some kind of "Prime Directive" to avoid contact with intelligent natives?

Comment: @user14111, I believe it was a series of stories. There's a chance that the same series involved space explorers trying to land a on very violent planet with lots of thunderstorms.

Comment: @user14111 Can't remember any robots, but to answer your last question, I have a feeling mission was aborted due to very high importance of finding another intelligent life form. Basically, the crew wasn't authorised to make first contact.